# Detect development server in asp.net (Visual Studio)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-development-serv

Can you programatically detect if the Development server in Visual Studio is used instead of IIS?

Comment: Is there a specific reason to do so? If you are merely trying to separate out environments, perhaps compilation flags would be better (i.e. DEBUG etc)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2010, Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_SOFTWARE") will return Nothing (null) for the Development Server, and "Microsoft-IIS/7.5" for my Win7 Pro IIS/VS2010 installation.